# Display all one page checkout steps at once (for development)

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, development

I want to style the onepage checkout and would like to make all steps visible temporarily for development, so I don't have to keep going through each step to style it.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: If my answer doesn't satisfy your need, you can give feedback.

Comment: frinds visit some help :-http://www.divisionlab.com/solvingmagento/onestep-checkout-a-magento-tutorial-part-1-steps-1-4-of-12/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of different extensions. You can try to install **free** one. **Main disadvantage of this approach is**: you need to fix everything yourself (but there are situations when this company offer prepaid support).

If you choose **paid** extension, in my opinion you have more chances to get with minimal bugs. If company care about their reputation - they will fix all bugs (which even appear in future) for free. If you have some custom theme or different extensions which affect checkout process - you can purchase support to fix compatibility between them.

I developed in one company such extensions, and I think - it is one of the most extensions which affect a lot of different core modules. And checkout is most important part of your shop.

So I'd recommend you to search on connect one page/step checkout and choose some in the top of the rating. Also try to reed reviews. And better read only negative reviews.

### Upd.1

Try to execute in browser console following command on checkout page:

```
jQuery('#checkoutSteps > li .step').css('display', 'block')
```

I think it will be better if you do it on summary step, because on this stage you will have filled all steps.
Using this script you will have only visual changes on your computer.

Comment: I'm not looking for a onepage checkout extension, I want to use the default checkout but disable each step temporary so I can style it. Hope this makes sense

Comment: You mean that you want to show all steps at least? What should happen when customer would like to edit shipping method at the first time? When you make available all steps - it doesn't matter will they be shown on one page or they will follow one by one. It means that your customer will have possibility to edit any step he likes.

Comment: I want to show all steps only whilst I'm styling it, once the site is live it will go back to normal. I only want to show all the steps temporarily

Comment: I hope i understand you. You are working with checkout design or smth like that. And you'd like to show steps while you are working with them. Once you finish - you 'd like to hide them again. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I want all steps visible

Comment: Ok. I'l look today. Rwd theme, right?

Comment: I've updated my post

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are couple of one page checkout modules on connect, that works as you have said.
I guess you wished for something like this [image]

[Here you go](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onecheckout-checkout-in-one-step-on-one-page.html), and it's free as well :)

Also, you can search for other with keyword `onepage checkout` on connect.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible and it would not make sense.

The payment and shipping steps depend on the address, and the review depends on all of them. So magento loads them with Ajax, which is why they would be empty anyway.

If you want to try it nevertheless, you can play with the accordion settings in [yourtheme]/checkout/one page.php.